# I cannot get informative error message for my nextflow code

Tags: nextflow

```
workflow fqcheck {
  take:
  path reads
  
  Channel.fromPath(reads)
    .map {file -> 
      def idx = ${file}.getName().replaceAll("\\D","")
      "fqcheck33 -r ${file} -c  ${file%.fq.gz}.${idx}.fqcheck"
    }

  publishDir params.outdir

}
workflow {
  fqcheck(ch_fq)
}
```

ch_fq should be a couple of fastqs. like sample.clean_1.fq.gz and sample.clean_2.fq.gz
I got nothing informative but " cause: Unexpected input: '{'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have provided doesn't look quite right. For one thing, the [`publishDir`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#publishdir) directive is something that you would apply to a [process](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html). I think you're looking for something like:

```
params.reads = './path/to/reads/*.clean_{1,2}.fq.gz'
params.outdir = './results'


process fqcheck33 {

    tag { sample }

    publishDir "${params.outdir}/fqcheck", mode: 'copy'

    input:
    tuple val(sample), path(fastq)

    output:
    tuple val(sample), path("${fastq.getBaseName(2)}.fqcheck")

    """
    fqcheck33 \\
        -r "${fastq}" \\
        -c "${fastq.getBaseName(2)}.fqcheck"
    """
}


workflow {

    reads = Channel.fromFilePairs( params.reads )

    fqcheck33( reads.transpose() )
}
```

The above just uses the [`transpose`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#transpose) operator to send each FASTQ file in the pair to the `fqcheck33` process, which expects a [tuple](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#input-type-tuple) where the first element is the sample name and the second is the FASTQ file.

Comment: Thanks Steve! But what if I simply want pass each fastq file in a list to fqcheck33? code is like this: `workflow {   filter(ch_id).set {ch_fq}   /* pass each file in ch_fq to fqcheck33 */ }` I tried fqcheck33(ch_fq) but got error like nextflow.util.BlankSeparatedList.getBaseName() is applicable for argument types: (Integer) values... sorry Im a newbie to nextflow!! Thanks for your help again!

Comment: @CaiBian My example above is expecting a tuple of inputs, but it sounds like `filter(ch_id)` emits lists of FASTQ files. Ideally, you need some way to transform these to match the input configuration of the `fqcheck33` process. One way would be to have your `filter` process produce tuples that include the sample name (or similar) as the first element and the list of FASTQ files as the second element. Then, like in the above example, use the `transpose` operator to produce the inputs for the `fqcheck33` process. For example: `workflow { filter(ch_id) | transpose | fqcheck33 }`

Comment: @CaiBian Ultimately, there's lots of ways to achieve what you want. Please consider [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75948202/edit) your question to include the details. For example, what does your `filter` process do? How is `ch_id` created? Note that Nextflow already has a [filter](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#filter) operator, so you may want to consider using a more expressive process name (e.g. `filter_reads`) to avoid any confusion.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! I think what I need is flatten()